# 'Step into' is not working when using LLDB

Tags: c++, debugging, cmake, clion, lldb

**Given:** a C++/CMake project build with g++ and debugged with LLDB.

OS: Ubuntu 20.04, Arch: x86_64

**Problem:**
'Step into' command does not step into a function, but steps over it instead. If I set a breakpoint inside the function I am trying to step into, it gets hit.
GDB works just fine.

Same behavior is observed when building the project with VSCode+plugins or CLion.

I tried hard searching for solutions, but could not find anything even remotely useful.

**Question:**
Do you have any leads or ideas on how to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: When you set a breakpoint and stop in the function, does the function you stop in have source information, or does lldb just show disassembly?  If the latter, then that's expected behavior, by default lldb doesn't step into functions with no debug information.

Comment: If it's not that, then if you can provide a reproducer, please file a bug with https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues?q=label%3Alldb with the code and any build instructions needed, where to set a breakpoint so we can see the failure, and how to run the program to hit the breakpoint.

Comment: We have lots of tests of stepping behavior which all pass on Ubuntu Linux; something specific to your situation is causing the problem.  So there's no good way to help w/o seeing specifics.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
settings clear target.process.thread.step-avoid-regexp
```

If that fixes it you must have had your step-avoid regex matching a little more broadly than you had expected. Should be easier to narrow down from there.